# box-shadow родительского элемента

Tags: html, css

Как наложить тень внутрь родительского блока так, чтобы можно было взаимодействовать с дочерними элементами?
Когда я пытался это реализовать, столкнулся с тем, что моя тень в виде псевдоэлемента `::before` перекрывала все дочерние блоки собой

```css
.parent {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: yellow;
}

.parent::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0px -9px 16px -3px #000000 inset;
  z-index: 100;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    какой-то текст или элемент с которым надо взаимодействовать и который может перекрывать тень родительского блока, если не установить z-index родительского элемента выше.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Я не понял, а чем вам box-shadow на самом элементе не угодил?

Comment: @AlexeyTen Дело в том, что тень на самом элементе перекрывается дочерними блоками. Ответ ниже мне помог.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы не было таких "перекрытий" дочерними (или другими) элементами, пользуйтесь свойством [`pointer-events: none`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events)

```css
.parent {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: yellow;
}

.parent::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0px -9px 16px -3px #000000 inset;
  z-index: 100;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    какой-то текст или элемент с которым надо взаимодействовать и который может перекрывать тень родительского блока, если не установить z-index родительского элемента выше.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: не знал про такое свойство. Спасибо !